# Chamada na API não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

estou com o seguinte código:

**// Script Jquery**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**// Script JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://revistadesignmagazine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    }
}).done(function ( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Quando realizo a chamada obtenho o seguinte erro:

*"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://revistadesignmagazine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."*

Como receber o data da chamada sem erros e exibir somente o título das postagens?

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem acesso ao wordpress, você pode adicionar ao functions.php dentro do tema usado: (usei essa função com o plugin wp-rest também)

```
/**
* Add REST API support to an already registered post type.
*/
/**
 * Use * for origin
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {

    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );

        return $value;

    });
}, 15 );
```

Caso você não tenha acesso, ai você precisa criar um middleware, um server que faz a request e responde esse dado da request, ex.: uma aplicação em node.js que quando você bate numa url, essa faz o get na sua api, pega os dados e retorna na request que você está fazendo.

Assim: get para http://seuapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts -> bate na url http://revistadesignmagazine.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts -> responde o conteúdo dessa url.

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente precisará adicionar o Header para CORS do lado do servidor (onde é gerado o json na url que você postou).

Em C# por exemplo, eu uso `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: Não tem jeito Júlio, isso está vindo do Wordpress